# continuity of a function with epsilon-delta-criterion

Tags: analysis

Check if the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\; x\mapsto \begin{cases}
  \frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}},  & \text{if }x\not=0\\
  0, & x=0
\end{cases}$
is continuous using the Epsilon-Delta criterion. 
The definition: f is continuous in $x_0=0\; \iff$ $\forall\epsilon >0 \exists \delta >0$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.
I have problems to find delta: 
I started with: $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x)|=|\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}|\le \frac{|x|}{e^{\frac{1}{|x|}}}<\frac{\delta}{e^{\frac{1}{\delta}}}<\epsilon$ is it correct? And I have to define $\delta$.. Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you did $|\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}|\le \frac{|x|}{e^{\frac{1}{|x|}}}$, you should instead use the fact that $e^{\frac{1}{x}}>0$ to get $|\frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}|\le |x|$.

Comment: ok, thank you! What is $\delta$ in this case, $\delta=\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, you should let $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: ok, thank you. This was helpful